# What does N'[Uncategorized (Local)] mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

The following code is seen in several Q&A code snippets here (and elsewhere),  I am trying to translate the section **N'[Uncategorized (Local)]**

```
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', 
       @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
```

Examples

- [SQL Job in idle state](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/)
- [Copy files using script to a network share](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34416)

I have looked at Microsoft [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.105).aspx)

> 'name'
>
> Is a valid user or login name. name must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role or exist as a principal in sys.database_principals or sys.server_principals, respectively.
> name cannot be a built-in account, such as NT AUTHORITY\LocalService, NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService, or NT AUTHORITY\LocalSystem.

and

> [N] 'command_string'
>
> Is a constant string that contains the command to be passed through to the linked server. If the N is included, the string is interpreted as nvarchar data type.

And I am guessing the section **N'[Uncategorized (Local)]** goes and gets the name of the sysadmin and passes it to execute the job as the sysadmin, but I am not finding a good reference that indicates how all three segments are working together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The @name parameter is a parameter of `msdb.dbo.sp_add_category` and not `EXEC`.

See the [sp_add_category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181597.aspx) documentation:

> [ @name = ] 'name'
>
> The name of the category to be added. The name must be unique within the specified class. name is sysname, with no default.

`[Uncategorized (Local)]` just indicates a default category when you didn't specify a category on the SQL Agent Job. The leading `N` just indicates the string is `nvarchar` and not `varchar`.

Please read through [Organize Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510207.aspx) to learn more about job categories

The code you are looking at is most likely just a scripted out job. For example when I right-click a random job on the SQL Server I'm looking at and `script job as > create > new query editor window` this is the result:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Warmup_SSRS_EP', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=3, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Warmup_SSRS_EP', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'domain\user', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'monitor operator', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
```

Where the creation of the category is just included in the script to make sure it exists because otherwise the following procedures would error out.